# Macbook Air 2015 wifi adapter not found issue

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, macbook

What happened:

- Wifi stopped working.
- 'Wifi' tab inside settings says 'no wifi adapter found'.
- Reboot does not help.

Diagnostics:

`lspci` shows:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0117]
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

so the adapter is still there -- likely a driver issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

`apt list --upgradeable` shows:

- bcmwl-kernel-source

as a package not in latest version.

Running `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source` fixed the issue.